# Referencing Data From a 2D Histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code that reads data from a CSV file and creates a 2D histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read in CSV data
filename = 'Complete_Storms_All_US_Only.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

min_85 = df.min85
min_37 = df.min37
verification = df.one_min_15

#Numbers
x = min_85
y = min_37
H = verification

#Estimate the 2D histogram
nbins = 33
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=nbins)

#Rotate and flip H
H = np.rot90(H)
H = np.flipud(H)

#Mask zeros
Hmasked = np.ma.masked_where(H==0,H)

#Calculate Averages
avgarr = np.zeros((nbins, nbins))
xbins = np.digitize(x, xedges[1:-1])
ybins = np.digitize(y, yedges[1:-1])
for xb, yb, v in zip(xbins, ybins, verification):
  avgarr[yb, xb] += v
divisor = H.copy()
divisor[divisor==0.0] = np.nan
avgarr /= divisor
binavg = np.around((avgarr * 100), decimals=1)
binper = np.ma.array(binavg, mask=np.isnan(binavg))

#Plot 2D histogram using pcolor
fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xedges,yedges,binper)
plt.title('1 minute at +/- 0.15 degrees')
plt.xlabel('min 85 GHz PCT (K)')
plt.ylabel('min 37 GHz PCT (K)')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Probability of CG Lightning (%)')

plt.show()
```

Each pixel in the histogram contains the probability of lightning for a given range of temperatures at two different frequencies on the x and y axis (`min_85` on the x axis and `min_37` on the y axis).  I am trying to reference the probability of lightning from the histogram based on a wide range of temperatures that vary on an individual basis for any given storm.  Each storm has a `min_85` and `min_37` that corresponds to a probability from the 2D histogram. I know there is a brute-force method where you can create a ridiculous amount of `if` statements, with one for each pixel, but this is tedious and inefficient when trying to incorporate over multiple 2D histograms. Is there a more efficient way to reference the probability from the histogram based on the given `min_85` and `min_37`? I have a separate file with the `min_85` and `min_37` data for a large amount of storms, I just need to assign the corresponding probability of lightning from the histogram to each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like all you need to do is turn the `min_85` and `min_37` values into indices.  Something like this will work:

```
# min85data and min37data from your file
dx = xedges[1] - xedges[0]
dy = yedges[1] - yedges[0]
min85inds = np.floor((min85data - yedges[1]) / dx).astype(np.int)
min37inds = np.floor((min37data - yedges[0]) / dy).astype(np.int)

# Pretend you didn't do all that flipping of H, or make a copy of it first
hvals = h_orig[min85inds, min37ends]
```

But do make sure that the resulting indices are valid before you extract them.